# RegEx for bracket in Notepad++

Tags: regex, subtitle, square-bracket

I'm trying to create a special RegEx function in notepad++ to fix some subtitle txt files originally in Softni format, which use square brackets as special characters for italic command. These files are originally intended for Softni products, but when they are used in other subtitle applications, not all commands work as they should.

In Softni format, italic works by placing "[" and "]" around the text that is supposed to be in italic, such as below:

```
This text has an [italic expression]
```

When italic is applied for lines, there is only a need to place a single bracket at the beginning of the line (and the "]" closing bracket may, or may not be used).

```
[This entire line is in italic
```

When the subtitle has two lines, the italic may extend from the start until the end of the second line, or if there is a closing bracket that indicates the end of italic.

```
Line 1 with normal text and [italic text
that extends for the whole sencond line

Line 1 with some [italic text
that extends to some portion] of line 2

[Line 1 is in italic
and line 2 is in italic
```

So as you can see, for some lines, there is a command for start of italic, but no end character for the command (which would be "]")
In the case of Two lines, the second lines sometimes do not start with "[", indicating that they already start with italic.

With RegEx, I try to always specify start and end of italic for all lines. Since italic may start and/or end multiple times in a single line, the RegEx should account for that.

```
[Italic word], normal text, [italic again
```

For the case above, I was able to recognize the pattern that with this command:

```
^.*\[(?!.*\]).*$
```

And with the proper change, this line would end up like this

```
[Italic word], normal text, [italic again]
```

However, I could not find a RegEx for the example below:

```
second line with text in italic], normal text,[and another italic text].
```

Does someone have a clue? I could use a RegEx, that involves two lines for that such as this one

```
(^(?!.*\].*).*\[.*)(\r\n)(^(?!.*\[.*).*\])
```

But If I could accomplish that without this particular need, it would provide a much better code.

Comment: It would be handy of you could group the examples together with what parts of them must be matched.  You can try [`^[^\]\[\n]*(?:\r?\n[^\]\[\n]*)?\]|\[[^\]\[\n]*(?:\r?\n[^\]\[\n]*)?\]?`](https://regex101.com/r/tP8eC2/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negated character class with some trick to restrict it to work with one and the next lines, and using 2 alternatives since you want to match mutually exclusive positions of `]`:

```
^[^\]\[\n]*(?:\r?\n[^\]\[\n]*)?\]|\[[^\]\[\n]*(?:\r?\n[^\]\[\n]*)?\]?
```

The last `]` is optional due to `?` quantifier.

[image]

Comment: If your italicized texts are longer than 2 lines (although your examples state otherwise) and their number is unknown this approach will not work.

Comment: It did work to find the above sentences enclosed in square brackets (even between two lines). Unfortunately I was not able to use the complete code because there were occasions when I needed to find sentences with the above conditions, but at the same time the code would allow me to select the necessary portion and replace it with the necessary enclosing square brackets.

Comment: For example, I was able to find the below condition:  
`'Line 1 with normal text and [italic text  
that extends for the whole sencond line`  
but I could not replace this for the following patterns:  
`'Line 1 with normal text and [italic text]  
[that extends for the whole sencond line]`